# luxon endOf month resolving wrong date

Tags: javascript, luxon

i'm using luxon for date calculation and try to get the end of a month in german timezone.
I tried the following code, but it gave me '2022-08-30T23:59:59.999+02:00'.
But august has **31 days**.

```
DateTime.fromISO('2022-07-31T10:00:00')
            .setZone("Europe/Berlin")
            .plus({month: 1})
            .endOf('month')
            .toString() // '2022-08-30T23:59:59.999+02:00'
```

(https://codesandbox.io/s/luxon-playground-forked-srh81m)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that issue showed in the linked CodeSandbox is due to old version of luxon used (`1.2.0`).

You'll get the expected result using version >= `1.21.2`, see [changelog](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1212-2019-11-18):

> **1.21.2 (2019-11-18)**
>
> - Fix bug in Chrome Canary that threw off time zone calculations

Working example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log(
DateTime.fromISO('2022-07-31T10:00:00')
            .setZone("Europe/Berlin")
            .plus({month: 1})
            .endOf('month')
            .toString() 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.21.2/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much. That fixed it. I already started to mistrust luxon.

Answer (score 0):

> Before addressing your question, a quick observation:
>
> The code in the CodeSandbox link that you shared doesn't seem to relate to the details in [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73187118/1), and I'm responding below to the details of your question (not what's at the external link):

Let's look at what each function returns in your method chain:

- [`DateTime.fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso) - *Create a DateTime from an ISO 8601 string*
- [`DateTime.prototype.setZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone) - *"Set" the DateTime's zone to specified zone. Returns a newly-constructed DateTime.*
- [`DateTime.prototype.plus`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeplus) - *Add a period of time to this DateTime and return the resulting DateTime*
- [`DateTime.prototype.endOf`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeendof) - *"Set" this DateTime to the end (meaning the last millisecond) of a unit of time*
- [`DateTime.prototype.toString`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetostring) - *Returns a string representation of this DateTime appropriate for debugging*

> Keep in mind that [all Luxon objects are immutable](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/tour?id=immutability). None of these mutate anything: they all return new DateTime instances.

The [`fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso) method accepts an options object as a second argument, and this object has an optional `zone` property, which is set to `"local"` by default. If you don't provide this option when creating a DateTime from an ISO string (and — like in your example — that string doesn't include time zone information), then the initial DateTime instance will configured to the time zone of the JS runtime environment of your code (typically set by the host operating system), and the date and time information in the string will be interpreted as though it is in that time zone.

Because of this, if you are providing an ISO string without zone information (but you want to use a specific zone), you should provide the option at the time of instantiation, like this:

```js
const dateStr = '2022-07-31T10:00:00';
const zone = 'Europe/Berlin';

const dt = DateTime.fromISO(dateStr, {zone});
```

Setting the zone this way produces the expected conversion result in the debug string:

```html
<script type="module">

import {DateTime} from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@3.0.1/build/es6/luxon.js';

const dateStr = '2022-07-31T10:00:00';
const zone = 'Europe/Berlin';

const resultStr = DateTime.fromISO(dateStr, {zone})
  .plus({month: 1})
  .endOf('month')
  .toString();

console.log({resultStr}); // { resultStr: "2022-08-31T23:59:59.999+02:00" }

</script>
```

Finally — while not directly related to your question — since you seem to be converting dates with Luxon, keep in mind that it has two [conversion accuracy modes: "casual" and "longterm"](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=casual-vs-longterm-conversion-accuracy).